# Even Dimensional Spheres and Lie Algebra Inclusions

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

The even dimensional spheres are homogeneous spaces of the form $S^{2n} = SO(2n+1)/SO(2n)$. What is the inclusions of Lie algebras $\frak{so}(2n) \hookrightarrow \frak{so}(2n+1)$ dual to the inclusion of groups $SO(2n) \hookrightarrow SO(2n+1)$. That is to say, where does the inclusion send the basis elements $E_i,F_i,K_i \in \frak{so}(2n)$, for $i =1,2$.

Comment: I reckon $SO(n)/SO(n-1)$ is more like $S^{n-1}$ than $S^{2n}$.

Comment: woops! Corrected now!

Comment: Do you really mean "... *dual* to the inclusion of groups ..." or would something like "*corresponding*" be a better word here? (In some sort of duality, I would expect arrows to be reversed.)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathfrak{so}_n(K)=\{A \in M_n(K) \mid A^T+A=0\}$, and we can embed a skew-symmetric matrix of size $2n$ into one of size $2n+1$ in the obvious way, just by adding a zero column and zero row.

Comment: I was hoping for some in terms of the abstract generators $E,F,K$.

Comment: The generators $E_i,F_i,K_i$ are skew-symmetric matrices, too. So no problem.

Comment: This is how I would do it, but one should keep in mind that one chooses bases here and "the" inclusion depends on that, i.e. is very non-functorial. Accordingly, on the root level, you will get one inclusion of the root system $D_n$ into $B_n$, but if you look at the roots and their automorphisms, there are many copies of $D_n$ in $B_n$, none of them "standing out".